# Blender camera window

Tags: 3d-view, camera, navigation

I am setting camera for my render. But my camera Window is so small. the tutorial am following to learn Blender has a bigger screen.

Can I make my Blender camera window bigger? I cant see anything through the camera. :(

What I dnt understand is if unity is same and am following him verbatim then why we have so much difference between his camera window and mine?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Uncheck the setting that moves the camera with the view, then zoom in, then enable the setting again.

Comment: Please use proper tags for your questions. The [tag:blender-internal-render-engine] is for questions about the legacy render engine *Blender Internal* that was shipped with Blender 2.79 and earlier versions.If you have questions about the 3D View please use the corresponding tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to zoom in, if zooming change the view of the camera and not its size in the window, it must be because you've enabled the *View Lock > Camera to View* option in the *N* panel:

[image]

Comment: He told me to do that :@ grrrrr

Comment: Yes it's a good idea when you want to move the camera in the scene, just disable it when you want to make the frame size bigger in the 3D view  ;)

Comment: It worked. Thanks :D